# multiple condition in the term or put match all in the term condition elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

how to query two different type in the elasticsearch.

As an example i have put the condition to fetch data where the data type is both male and female.

But it is not working for me.

Any one knows how to put multiple condition in the term or put match all in the term condition.

```
   $typefilter = array('male', 'female');
   if ($request->request->get('male') && $request->request->get('female') ) {
                $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][] = array(
                    'term' => array(
                        "type" => implode(" ", $type)
                    )
                );
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `terms` instead of `term`

```
   $typefilter = array('male', 'female');
   if ($request->request->get('male') && $request->request->get('female') ) {
                $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][] = array(
                    'terms' => array(                    <--- CHANGE HERE
                        "type" => $typefilter            <--- CHANGE HERE
                    )
                );
            }
```